# How to assign dynamically created objects to a string?

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls

I have a form with this code assigned to a button:

```
    TextBox[] tbxCantServ = new TextBox[1];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < tbxCantServ.Length; i++)
    {
        tbxCantServ[i] = new TextBox();
    }

    foreach (TextBox tbxActualCant in tbxCantServ)
    {
        tbxActualCant.Location = new Point(iHorizontal, iVertical);
        tbxActualCant.Visible = true;
        tbxActualCant.Width = 44;
        tbxActualCant.MaxLength = 4;
        this.Controls.Add(tbxActualCant);
        iVertical = iVertical + 35;
    }
```

And this code creates textboxes dynamically, one for every "button click", so I can have an "add" button to call it and the user can write a list of things that is not limited.

The question is: How can I assign these "textboxes.Text" to a string? They haven't got a name :S

something like:

```
string sAllBoxes = tbx1.Text + tbx2.Text + "..." + tbxN.Text;
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `tbxCantServ` is **defined as local** to a method, then you have to assign a `Name` to your TextBoxes like:

```
int counter = 0;
foreach (TextBox tbxActualCant in tbxCantServ)
{
    tbxActualCant.Location = new Point(iHorizontal, iVertical);
    tbxActualCant.Name = "tbx" + counter++;
    tbxActualCant.Visible = true;
    tbxActualCant.Width = 44;
    tbxActualCant.MaxLength = 4;
    this.Controls.Add(tbxActualCant);
    iVertical = iVertical + 35;
}
```

And later in some other method if you want to get the joined text then you can do:

```
string sAllBoxes = string.Join(",", this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                                .Where(r => r.Name.StartsWith("tbx"))
                                .Select(r => r.Text));
```

But if you have `tbxCantServ` defined at class level then you can do:

```
string sAllBoxes = string.Join(",", tbxCantServ
                                     .Where(r=> r != null)
                                     .Select(r => r.Text));
```

*In `string.Join`, you can replace `,` with an empty string or any string depending on your requirement.*

Comment: Thanks, I am trying with this but I get a syntax error with the: tbxCantServ
                                     .Where(r=> r != null)
                                     .Select(r => r.Text)); part. How can I correct it?

Comment: @user3108594, there shouldn't be any space before `.Where` and `.Select`. , Should be like:  `tbxCantServ.Where(r=> r != null).Select(r => r.Text));`

Comment: I got cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'.

Comment: What is your current .Net framework ? I believe you are using .Net framework 3.5. Just add `ToArray` like `tbxCantServ.Where(r=> r != null).Select(r => r.Text).ToArray()); `

Comment: Thanks, now it's working! I use 2.0 for compatibility, so I used the LinqBridge to call it :P

Comment: @user3108594, you are welcome. But you can use a simple loop and add to `StringBuilder` instead of using LINQ at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in the same way you created them.

Try this:

```
string sAllBoxes="";
foreach (TextBox tbxActualCant in tbxCantServ)
{
     sAllBoxes+=tbxActualCant.Text;
}
```

**OR**

Using a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder textBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (TextBox tbxActualCant in tbxCantServ)
{
     textBuilder.Append(tbxActualCant.Text);
}
string allText = textBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you need `StringBuilder` over `string` ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to your textbox array, you can easily do this:

```
string sAllBoxes = string.Join(" ", tbxCantServ.Select(x => x.Text));
```

If you don't then use `Control` collection of your `Form`, and give name to your textboxes so you can access them using `this.Controls[txtBoxName]`.

If you just want to concatanate your texts without a separator, you can also use `string.Concat` method:

```
string sAllBoxes = string.Concat(tbxCantServ.Select(x => x.Text));
```

Comment: Why space in `Join` which is not specified by OP?

Comment: that `"..."` confused me.I thought he wants a separator (most likely), otherwise `string.Concat` can be used.

Comment: I guess that `...` emphasizes he may have `N` number of items. 1,2,3... and so on upto n.